# running chained bash function commands in background

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, bash, bash-scripting, .bash-profile

I am attempting to call

```
port() { fuser -k $1/tcp; python manage.py runserver $1 ;}
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 & ; sleep 3 ; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$2 ;}
```

(`port` is a django style server).
on source it errors out with

```
cchilders:~/projects/scriptamajig [master]$ src
bash: /home/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 134: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: /home/cchilders/.bash_profile: line 134: `runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 & ; sleep 3 ; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$2 ;} '
```

my `google-chrome` command will not open, I think because `port $2` runs the django server and hogs the terminal pipe. The `sleep` part doesn't even run after port runs. I want to run `port` in the background and keep chaining after that; what is the syntax for backgrounding in a function (not an alias)? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This isn't due to the function, it's because you're chaining multiple commands on a line with `;` separating them. But `&` is already a command separator, and using both without a command in between (as in `... port $2 & ; sleep 3 ...`) is a syntax error. Solution: either remove the redundant `;`:

```
runproject() { cd $HOME/projects/$1 ; workon $1 ; port $2 & sleep 3 ; google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$2 ;}
```

Or use line breaks as command separators, instead of `;`:

```
runproject() {
    cd $HOME/projects/$1
    workon $1
    port $2 &
    sleep 3
    google-chrome 127.0.0.1:$2
}
```

...which I prefer, because I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can background a bash function like you would a program

```
imahappyfunction()
{
    sleep 50000
}

imahappyfunction &
```